# Calling .dll build with /clr:netcore from unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, clr, managed, unmanagedexports

I have an unmanaged C++ applications that connects to different data sources via vendor DLLs.
For .Net framework DLLs I used to create /clr projects and it worked for me without any problems.

But now I need to use .Net 5 DLL, and can't make it work that way. to mix unmanaged and .net 5 code I have to use /clr:netcore which builds only as DLL, but my app should be a windows service, so I created a wrapper DLL for vendors .Net 5 DLL using /clr:netcore with a few exported methods(unmanaged). Used .def file to specify exported methods.

```
wrapper.h
    typedef int(__stdcall* PHCallback)(void* client, LPCTSTR strItem, void* data);

    void* __declspec(dllexport) CreateClient(LPCTSTR params);
    bool __declspec(dllexport) Connect(void* client);
    void __declspec(dllexport) SetCallback(void* client, PHCallback* pCallback);
    void __declspec(dllexport) SendRequest(void* client, LPCTSTR request);
```

In this wrapper CreateClient creates an instance of an object defined in vendor's DLL so I could use it later in other methods. SetCallback sets a callback to be called when data is ready, nothing special.

Compiled the Wrapper.dll got .lib and .dll files - all good so far.

Then I tried to link my unmanaged app with that Wrapper.dll (using header file and .lib).
Everything compiled fine... but when I try to launch/debug my app I got an error 'A dependent dll was not found'.

All .lib/.dll/.exe are in the same directory.
If I open .exe with DependancyWalker - it says it can't find wrapper.dll too(why?)
If I open wrapper.dll directly in DependancyWalker - it's shown and all my exported methods are there.

So what do I need to make this work? Or is it impossible to use .net 5.0 DLLs from unmanaged c++ this way?

I

Comment: Targeting 5.0 is broken right now, it still works for 3.1.  So try that first to know you've got the basics correct, hopefully 6.0 will have the fix.

Comment: I have vendors dll compiled with .net 5.0, can't change this.